# Why to use ./ when referencing local files in HTML

Tags: html, css

In my html I need to reference both my css sheet, images etc. I was told to use ./ when referencing files or images in the same directory, but I noticed when I leave it out it doesn't matter.

```
<link href="./resources/css/style.css">
<img src="./resources/soy_luz_square_logo.jpg">
```

Work the same without './':

```
<link href="resources/css/style.css">
<img src="resources/soy_luz_square_logo.jpg">
```

Is there usage I'm missing under certain circumstances?

Comment: Because some people like to do it and some people don't.

Comment: There's no difference at all. `./` makes more obvious for humans that it's meant to be a relative link and it isn't an absolute link that's missing the leading slash by mistake. But that's pretty much all. Please note that there're other contexts (namely many console shells) where it does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://superuser.com/questions/54027/path-difference-between-and, there is no difference in using one or other. But using ./ you certify you are in the current directory.